# What's the best thing to do if the OS X Performance Update hangs?

Tags: macos, updates

I closed all applications and then chose to install the Performance Update that was released this week (October 16, 2009). Upon rebooting I get a blue screen with the gray and black waiting circle. Is it safe to just hold down the power button until the system shuts off and the restart?

Comment: **Update** I waited for 10 minutes and the system just stayed at the blue screen with the grey and black waiting spinner, so I held the power button down for 5 seconds and restarted the system. Upon restarting (which took much longer than normal), the Bluetooth is not available. I rebooted again and Bluetooth is still not available.

Comment: If Bluetooth is not available, try doing an SMC reset. It might sound like voodoo, but it worked for me. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1411

Comment: Thanks to Jared Harley for fixing all my typos. I'm clearly not an expert typist when forced to submit questions to SuperUser from my iPhone!

Comment: @Olly: You might want to make that an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: @Olly: Please make that an answer, as that was the answer to solving the Bluetooth problem. The boot time still seems a little longer than what I'm used to, but I'll review the logs with Console to figure what's up there. Thanks again.

Comment: @Matthew Rankin and Chealion; Done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Bluetooth is not available, try doing an SMC reset. It might sound like voodoo, but it worked for me. See [support.apple.com/kb/HT1411](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1411)

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with **v** pressed (verbose booting); maybe you'll spot something there. This might be a first step in diagnosing your problem. What's weird is that the performance update had nothing to do with bluetooth, it was hard drive related. You probably corrupted a file when you powered off the machine.

Comment: I tried booting with v pressed but didn't receive anything. I agree that the update didn't cause the bluetooth problem, except that the update didn't perform correctly, so I bet you're correct that something was corrupted during the process or when I powered off (although I can't believe that the update should take longer than 10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

The performance update was to do with the issue where hard drive read would stall. I don't see how it could have affected the bluetooth.

However, turning off the machine during boot could have resulted in damaging a file related to bluetooth.

I would recommend restoring your Mac to a backup (Time Machine, or otherwise) taken just before you installed the update.